# Is there a way to find the weights of every feature in spark ml model?

Tags: classification, logistic-regression, apache-spark, prediction, naive-bayes-classifier

I am using spark ml classifier to create a model to predict whether a user will buy a product or not and I am using features both continuous and categorical. The model is predicting the outcome with some accuracy. Is there a way to see how much each feature is contributing to the prediction (i.e) the weight of each feature in the model created from training data? Because I need to know why a user will buy a product or not. I am using spark 2.0.0 and all the classifiers available in it

Thanks in Advance